# gspread TypeError: login() takes no arguments (2 given)

Tags: python, gdata, google-data-api, gspread

I have installed **gspread** and gdata in my virtual environment using pip. And when I try to login with email and password following the documentation, as shown:

```
import gspread
gc = gspread.login('533ghimiresantosh@gmail.com','password')
```

It throws this error: `TypeError: login() takes no arguments (2 given)`

gspread is installed properly which is confirmed by successful execution of line `import gspread` in the python console. Is there some dependency issue that I am unaware of or anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to `login` like this

```
c = gspread.Client(auth=('user@example.com', 'qwertypassword'))
c.login()
```

**source** http://burnash.github.io/gspread/#gspread.Client.open

Answer (score 0):

Using the latest version I can still do it: gc = gspread.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD)